# Does Cloud9 store BBB programs on the Internet?

Tags: cloud, cloud9-ide, beagleboneblack

Quick Question.  My BeagleBone just died on me - its power LED only blinks for a moment before shutting off.  I've already ordered a replacement though.  Now, I've been working on some code for it that I was running via the Cloud9 IDE. I want to know if there's anyway I can somehow recover that code either right now or once I get the new board.  Will the cloud9 programs appear again when I connect to the new BBB?  Or are they stored on the hard drive of the dead BBB and thus unrecoverable?

Also, right before the BBB died, it was running an html webpage.  This webpage used sockets coming from a node.js file running on Cloud9.  Is there anyway to view the node.js file from Google Chrome's Javascript console? Right now, I can only find the .html code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Cloud9 stores it on the board. There are plans for making this cloud connected, but that has not materialized yet. Sorry for your loss.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no it does not. I'm pretty sure it just stores all information on the board itself.